# The name does not exist in the current context

Tags: asp.net

I have a masterpage in my asp.net 3.5 application and I have some controls and jquery stuff. I try to access the controls in codebehind and it says :

```
The name 'DrpStates' does not exist in the current context
```

Why it is not accessible in codebehind ?

Comment: which project r u using Web Application or website?

Comment: Please post your form Design, so that we can understand your problem.

Answer (score 9):

When you create a code behind file, ASP.NET also automatically generates a designer file (which is right next to it). In that designer file all the controls are initialized and loaded. Sometimes (for reasons unknown) when you create a new control, it fails to re-initialize the designer file and you can't get access to the control in the code behind file.

Try doing this >

1. Delete the designer file (right click > delete)
2. Right click on the aspx file > Convert to Web Application

Should work now

Comment: I deleted the designer file next to my page temp5.aspx and converted to web application but still same error

Comment: I have deleted the designer file and I dont have any designer file. aspx page is very large

Comment: @Govind I see that designer file is empty. not sure why ?

Comment: declaring the control yourself is not a good idea. Whenever you insert a new control in your aspx page,the designer is generated again and your changes would be lost. never mess with the designer manually. you need to show us your aspx file, for some reason it's not correctly linked to designer/code behind file.

Comment: I faced the same problem earlier and I solve that style I didn't face any problem for that page again...

Comment: well I guess you also copied the first two lines starting with `<%Page..` too which messed up their linkage with designer/code behind files. Can you show us your top headers on the aspx file ?

Comment: Thanks, this works when you manually copy code from a website or something.  I struggled with this for hours.  So simple!

Answer (score 2):

It's probably part of the master page or parent page, try using `FindControl` method:

```
this.Page.FindControl("DrpStates");
```

Comment: @naveed you mean it's directly in the `.aspx` and the failing code is in the `.aspx.cs` code?

Answer (score 0):

There could be a problem with your .designer.cs file. Check if you have a designer file with the same name as your aspx (or ascx) file.

If you open the aspx file and switch between design view and html view and back it will prompt VS to check the controls and add any that are missing to the designer file.

Try right clicking on the aspx and select "Convert to Web Application".

You can also try deleting the .designer.cs file and then recreate an empty file with the same name.

Answer (score 0):

reason : - When we create a code behind file, ASP.NET also automatically generates a designer file. In that designer file all the controls are initialized and loaded. Sometimes when we create a new control, it fails to re-initialize the designer file and you can't get access to the control in the code behind file.

There is a simple Solution to this situation.

Step1 : open the the yourfile.aspx.designer.cs file

- you will find things like " protected global::System.Web.UI.WebControls.Label Label2; "
- these are the initialized components in the sequence in which they were generated by you.

Step2: just copy and paste the following line repeatedly for every missing component that were not
       recognized by the code behind : "global::System.Web.UI.WebControls."+Class of the component that you are missing + single space + id of the missing component.

Step3: save the file and voila all the components error disappear magically.